# Fetching Video from API in Angular facing HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to fetching an Video from api but once i get the video from api it throws an error:-
**Http failure during parsing for http://url/training/getMedia?path=C:/home/video71146ca7-3df2-4888-8e30-ac8f1d2ce583video.mp4**

service:-

```
getVideo(path){
    console.log(path);
    const opts = new HttpParams().set('path',path);
    return this.http.get('http://url/getMedia',{params:opts});
  }
```

component:-

```
getVideo(path){
    console.log(path);
    this.createTraining.getVideo(path).subscribe(event=>{console.log(event)
    this.show = true;
    this.url = event;
    });
```

[image: Full error]

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I directly fetch from the link no need to call api.